# How does hard mode work?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

From what I heard, flashpoints have a "hard mode".

How do I activate it? How much harder is it? Do all flashpoints have it? Are there other differences between normal mode and hard mode I should know about?

Comment: Are you familiar with World of Warcraft's "Heroic Dungeons"? Basically that.

Comment: Never played WoW, so no.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hard Modes are more challenging versions of the original Flashpoints reserved for high-level players. All the mobs and bosses are raised to the required level and drop loot appropriate for their difficulty.  There are some new fight mechanics but the Flashpoints have the same story and progression.

Not all Flashpoints have a Hard Mode.  The following eleven flashpoints have a Level 50 Hard Mode:

- The Esseles (level 10, Republic only)
- Black Talon (level 10, Empire only)
- Taral V (level 33, Republic only)
- Boarding Party (level 33, Empire only)
- Maelstrom Prison (level 37, Republic only)
- The Foundry (level 37, Empire only)
- Directive 7 (level 49)
- The Battle of Ilum (level 50)
- The False Emperor (level 50)
- Kaon Under Siege (level 50)
- Lost Island (level 50)

These are Story Mode only:

- Colicoid War Game (level 41)
- Red Reaper (level 45)

Additionally, these four have had a Level 55 Hard Mode added in [Patch 2.0](http://www.swtor.com/patchnotes/2.0-rothc/rise-hutt-cartel-and-scum-and-villainy):

- Hammer Station (level 17)
- Athiss (level 21)
- Mandalorian Raiders (level 25)
- Cademimu (level 29)

[Game Update 2.3](http://www.swtor.com/patchnotes/2.3/titans-industry) added two 55 Flashpoints with both Story and Hard modes, with Story allowing any group composition:

- Czerka Corporate Labs
- Czerka Core Meltdown

Flashpoints since then have followed that format of allowing any group composition and are called Tacticals.  The following scale to the level of the highest group member, and only 55s are allowed to group with 55s for them (levels 15-54 are bolstered to the same level):

- Kuat Drive Yards (added with [Patch 2.6](http://www.swtor.com/patchnotes/242014/game-update-2.6-galactic-starfighter))
- Assault on Tython (added with [Patch 2.7](http://www.swtor.com/patchnotes/482014/game-update-2.7-invasion))
- Korriban Incursion (added with Patch 2.7)
- Depths of Manaan (added with [Patch 2.9](http://www.swtor.com/patchnotes/8192014/game-update-2.9-galactic-strongholds-early-access))
- Legacy of the Rakata (added with [Patch 2.10](http://www.swtor.com/patchnotes/992014/game-update-2.10-forged-alliances-patch-notes))

In order to do the hard mode, you must have completed the normal mode version of the "Flashpoint Quest", dispensed from the an NPC just outside the flashpoint. After talking to that NPC again, at the appropriate level and after completing the normal quest, he will offer you the hard mode version of the quest instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found comprehensive guides for all the flashpoints, nor have I done them all on hard mode. In general, they are as the name suggests, "more difficult".

Comment: In all the ones I've played "More difficult" basically boiled down to "The enemies are now level 50/55 and some of the bosses have extra mechanics"